# Best bayesian network program for mac?

Tags: bayesian, software, bayesian-network

Does anyone know which is the best bayesian network program for mac that has a graphical interface and is free?

Comment: What do you mean by bayesian network program?

Comment: @mbq a program where you can specify bayesian networks as directed acyclic graphs representing the probabilistic relations between variables and can do inference from those relations. programs like AgenaRisk or Genie for mac and for free

Comment: As a software recommendation question, I think this would now be considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

[SAMIAM](http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/samiam/help/) software is recommended by prof. Daphne Koller at her Stanford's class "Probabilistic graphical models". It has a version for MACs as well.

Comment: (+1) Well done. (32-bit only Mac version)